# Delete element from multi-dimensional array based on key

Tags: php, arrays

How can I delete an element from a multi-dimensional array given a key?

I am hoping for this to be greedy so that it deletes all elements in an array that match the keys I pass in. I have this so far where I can traverse a multi-dimensional array but I can't unset the key I need to because I don't have a reference to it!

```
function traverseArray($array, $keys)
{ 
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    { 
        if(is_array($value))
        { 
            traverseArray($value); 

        } else {

            if(in_array($key, $keys))
           {                    
                //unset(what goes here?) 

            }

        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: I think `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated`. Especially since I am using this in a class in Code-igniter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code works (and doesn't use deprecated stuff), just tested it:

```
function traverseArray(&$array, $keys) { 
  foreach ($array as $key => &$value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      traverseArray($value, $keys); 
    } else {
      if (in_array($key, $keys)){
        unset($array[$key]);
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This was very useful, thanks @Marian. If anyone uses this and wants to perform a check on the VALUE of the element you're removing, you can check `$value` just before performing `unset()`;

Answer (score 1):

You could use pass by reference, declare your function like this:

```
function traverseArray(&$array, $keys)
{ 
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    { 
        if(is_array($value))
        { 
            traverseArray($value, $keys); 
        }else{
            if(in_array($key, $keys)){
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

then you can unset the key and it will vanish from the original passed value too since the `$array` in the function is merely a pointer to the array you passed so it updates that array.

```
unset($array[$key]);
```

For more information check the [php documentation on passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: I get this message `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated`. I am using this in a class in Codeigniter.

Comment: I edited my answer to include your whole function. Additionally you need to make sure that when you call it you use `traverseArray($array, $keys)` and **not** `traverseArray(&$array, $keys)`

Comment: Right, I don't get that error anymore. However, the array is the same as before. I am wondering can this really work in a class? I am calling the above function from another function in a class and this function isn't returning anything. The way I call it is like so: `$this->traverseArray($errors, array('e1', 'e2'));`

Comment: @Abs Marian Galik beat me to finding the bug and his code works, Andrej L had already figured out that little part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
unset($array[$key]);
```

because `$array` will not be a copy of the original array, just a reference to it, so any modifications will hold.

Also, you have a small bug in your snippet: when you make the recursive call, you forget the pass the `$keys` parameter.

Comment: @sg3s in new versions (php5.x, don't know for sure) it's the default + the pass-by-reference `&$var` is deprecated. See this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138454/php-arrays-and-pass-by-reference) for clarification.

Comment: I'm quite sure @sg3's right. The `&` in a function call, like `foo(&$a);` is deprecated according to the manual, but otherwise it says `function foo(&$var) {`.

Answer (score 0):

and don't forget to modify foreach:

```
foreach($array as $key=>&$value)
```

Comment: You don't need to do this once a variable is referenced it will carry it through to all the uses of that variable afaik (someone feel to test this? :p)

Comment: You can't change array values in foreach.

Comment: What is reason for downvoting?