# PHP array to take out array value only one field

Tags: php

I have an array where i want only the one Field text from all array which is text only. i want all text from there.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [language] => en
    [textAngle] => 0
    [orientation] => Up
    [regions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [boundingBox] => 81,63,1340,1055
                    [lines] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [boundingBox] => 321,63,855,117
                                    [words] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 321,63,174,94
                                                    [text] => Set
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 529,87,126,69
                                                    [text] => an
                                                )

                                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 693,65,483,115
                                                    [text] => example.
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [boundingBox] => 218,182,1059,116
                                    [words] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 218,182,271,92
                                                    [text] => Treat
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 521,203,504,95
                                                    [text] => everyOne
                                                )

                                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [boundingBox] => 1054,182,223,91
                                                    [text] => With
                                                )

                                        )

                                )
```

I want take out from here like [text]=>Set,[text]=>an,[text]=>example.
eg set an example.

Output should be eg. only like set an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134824/delete-element-from-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key take a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example class above, I would try something like this.

```
$text = '';
foreach ($class->regions[0]->lines as $line){
    foreach ($line->words as $word){
        $text = $text." ".$word->text;
    } 
}
print $text;
```